# Firefox 87: hitting enter at "Enter search terms" doesn't go straight to search engine homepage

Tags: firefox, keyword-search

In Firefox 87, keyword searching with an empty keyword doesn't go straight to the search engine's homepage when I press enter; it forces me to enter a search term when it says:

[image: keyword search]

Is there a way to restore the old behavior, so hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> goes straight to the search engine's homepage?

<sub>cf. [r/firefox "Why is custom search broken now?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/lt2xfv/why_is_custom_search_broken_now/); [allegedly](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/08/31/first-look-at-firefoxs-upcoming-address-bar-update/), this is part of the so-called "Design Update 2".</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a bookmark and set its keyword to the key sequence you want.

"Use a single keyword to open bookmarks directly from the address bar".

For example, you could set "so" to go to StackOverflow, even if "so" is already bound to the StackOverflow search engine.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since [Firefox 83](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/83.0/releasenotes/). And it's pretty annoying.

You have now to press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on macOS) to make the search straight from the address bar when before you only had to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Has no effect for me on Linux.

Comment: I wrote incorrectly the key combination. It has to be all three keys at the same time: Control+Shift+Enter. Did you tried this? It works for me on Windows and macOS. I didn't have the chance to try on Linux.

Comment: I'm on Linux, and that doesn't work, either.